# rational points in singular quartic surface

Tags: number-theory, surfaces, birational-geometry

I came across the following quartic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$:
$S: xyz(x-2y-z)+ww(xy+2xz-yz) = 0$

(It seems that S has singularities at
$[x:y:z:w] = [1:0:0:0],[0:1:0:0],[0:0:1:0],[0:0:0:1]$.)

I'm interested in the rational points on $S$.
Is there some explicit way to obtain rational points (e.g. parametrized rational points) on $S$?

I guess that resolution of singularities may be related but I'm not familiar with explicit resolution of singularities.